# How to obtain JNI interface pointer (JNIEnv *) for asynchronous calls

Tags: java, c, multithreading, java-native-interface

I have learned that the JNI interface pointer (JNIEnv *) is only valid in the current thread. Suppose I started a new thread inside a native method; how it can asynchronously send events to a Java method? As this new thread can't have a reference of (JNIEnv *). Storing a global variable for (JNIEnv *) apparently will not work?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Within synchronous calls using JNI from Java to C++ the "environment" has already been setup by the JVM, however going in the other direction from an arbitrary C++ thread it may not have been

Therefore you need to follow these steps

- get hold of the JVM environment context using `GetEnv`
- attach the context if necessary using `AttachCurrentThread`
- call the method as normal using `CallVoidMethod`
- detach using `DetachCurrentThread`

Full example. Note I have written about this in the past in more detail on my [blog](http://www.adamish.com/blog/archives/327)

```
JavaVM* g_vm;
env->GetJavaVM(&g_vm);

void callback(int val) {
    JNIEnv * g_env;
    // double check it's all ok
    int getEnvStat = g_vm->GetEnv((void **)&g_env, JNI_VERSION_1_6);
    if (getEnvStat == JNI_EDETACHED) {
        std::cout << "GetEnv: not attached" << std::endl;
        if (g_vm->AttachCurrentThread((void **) &g_env, NULL) != 0) {
            std::cout << "Failed to attach" << std::endl;
        }
    } else if (getEnvStat == JNI_OK) {
        //
    } else if (getEnvStat == JNI_EVERSION) {
        std::cout << "GetEnv: version not supported" << std::endl;
    }

    g_env->CallVoidMethod(g_obj, g_mid, val);

    if (g_env->ExceptionCheck()) {
        g_env->ExceptionDescribe();
    }

    g_vm->DetachCurrentThread();
}
```

Comment: The only pieces of this answer that are related to the question are `GetEnv`, `AttachCurrentThread` and `DetachCurrentThread` and they are not even explained.

Comment: That solves my problem completely, however above explanation by main was beautiful

Comment: g_obj = env->NewGlobalRef(obj); -------> is throwing error: Request for member 'NewGlobalRef' in something not a structure or union

Comment: resolved the above error myself. I saved the file as .c but was using c++ syntax.

Comment: Thank you!  This seems to have fixed a very stubborn but intermittent problem in my app.

Comment: @Akhilesh quite nice explanation about global and local scope of references in JNI is in https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JavaNativeInterface.html#zz-7.

Comment: Shouldn't `DetachCurrentThread()` be conditioned to the execution of `AttachCurrentThread()` ?

Comment: Where do you get the `g_vm` variable from?

Comment: Wonder about the origin of `g_obj`; EDIT found in **blog** reference http://adamish.com/blog/archives/327

Comment: This looks like a very expensive operation. Has anyone measured it?

Comment: There is another use case for this solution: You want to trigger a callback using a global reference, when in the callback function by design the current environment in not available.

Answer (score 108):

You can obtain a pointer to the JVM (`JavaVM*`) with [`JNIEnv->GetJavaVM`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/functions.html#wp23168). You can safely store that pointer as a global variable. Later, in the new thread, you can either use [`AttachCurrentThread`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/invocation.html#attach_current_thread) to attach the new thread to the JVM if you created it in C/C++ or simply [`GetEnv`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/invocation.html#GetEnv) if you created the thread in java code which I do not assume since JNI would pass you a `JNIEnv*` then and you wouldn't have this problem.

```c
    // JNIEnv* env; (initialized somewhere else)
    JavaVM* jvm;
    env->GetJavaVM(&jvm);
    // now you can store jvm somewhere

    // in the new thread:
    JNIEnv* myNewEnv;
    JavaVMAttachArgs args;
    args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6; // choose your JNI version
    args.name = NULL; // you might want to give the java thread a name
    args.group = NULL; // you might want to assign the java thread to a ThreadGroup
    jvm->AttachCurrentThread((void**)&myNewEnv, &args);
    // And now you can use myNewEnv
```

Comment: Note that the second argument to `AttachCurrentThread` can be NULL if you don't need any special settings, and you should be sure to call `DetachCurrentThread` when you're finished if you weren't attached to begin with (otherwise you'll accumulate useless `Thread` objects that can't ever be GC'd).

Comment: the definition of AttachCurrentThread function changes in the NDK r9. here is the document link. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/invocation.html

Comment: Shouldn't `JNIEnv->GetJavaVM` accept `env` as the first parameter?

Comment: @DenisKniazhev `env` basically **is** the first parameter because `GetJavaVM` is invoked on the `env` pointer.

Comment: @main-- should it work in NDK while using pure C? I get "request for member 'GetJavaVM' in something not a structure or union" unless I call it like `(*env)->GetJavaVM(env, &jvm);`

Comment: @DenisKniazhev Correct. C doesn't have classes, so you can't invoke a method on a pointer. In C++, JNI provides wrapper classes that automatically pass the env pointer, but in C you have to pass it manually.