# JNI calling Java from C++ with multiple threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, java-native-interface, runtime-error

I'm working on a project, where I call Java functions from C++ code (using JNI) and I have a problem about multithreading. I want to call Java searching function and for each call I want to make a separate thread. I have a singleton `MainClass` and nested `Query` class. `Query` class is inherited from `QThread`. Code looks like this

```
MainClass::MyQuery query("<some search query>");
query.LaunchQuery();


//functions of Query   
void MainClass::MyQuery::LaunchQuery() const
{
    this->start();
}

void MainClass::Query::run()
{
    const MainClass& mainClass = MainClass::GetInstance();
    const jclass& obj = mainClass.GetClass();
    JNIEnv& env = mainClass.GetJavaEnvironment();
    jmethodID methodId = env.GetMethodID(obj, "SearchQuery", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V"); //Run-time error

    if(methodId != 0)
    {
        //calling "SearchQuery" function
    }
```

Now, if run this code in a single thread - everything is fine, but if try to run above code - using multithreading, it causes run-time error by message 
`"Unhandled exception at 0x777715de in MyApp.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x000000ac."` when I try to get method id. I've tried also with `boost::thread` but result was the same.

So why it fails when I'm doing it in a separate thread, when in the same thread everything is fine? 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Scroll down to 'Attaching to the VM' in the JNI docs :

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/invocation.html

> The JNI interface pointer (JNIEnv) is valid only in the current
>   thread. Should another thread need to access the Java VM, it must
>   first call AttachCurrentThread() to attach itself to the VM and obtain
>   a JNI interface pointer.

Comment: And I'll add an example for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12900695/how-to-obtain-jni-interface-pointer-jnienv-for-asynchronous-calls