# JNI: Does C++ calls Java asynchronous?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I'm trying to call some java classes from c++ code by using the JNI. Today I experienced a very strange behaviour in my programm. I suspect that the c++ code is not wait until the java side finished it's work and I don't know why.

The C++ code (in a shared object library) is running in it's own C++ thread. It is using a existing JavaVM of a java app that is already up and running. The references to the VM and the ClassLoader where fetched while the java application was loading the shared object library in JNI_Onload. Here I call the java method of a java object I created with JNI in the C++ thread:

```
env->CallVoidMethod(javaClassObject, javaReceiveMethod, intParam, byteParam, objectParam);
uint32_t applicationSideResponseCode = getResponseCode(objectClass, objectParam, env);
resp.setResponseCode(applicationSideResponseCode);
std::string applicationData = getApplicationData(serviceResultClass, serviceResultObject, env);
resp.setData(applicationData);
```

The Java `javaReceiveMethod` is accessing the database and fetching some `applicationData` which is stored in the `objectParam`. Unfortunately the C++ code fetched the applicationData before the java class completed it's work. applicationData is `null` and the JNI crashes. Why? I can't find any documentation of Oracle stating that CallVoidMethod is executed asynchronous?

**Edit**

I verified that no exception has occured on the java method. Everything seems fine, except that Java is still busy while C++ is trying to access the data.

**Edit**

I can confirm that if I debug the java application two threads are shown. On main thread, that is executing `javaReceiveMethod` and one thread that is fetching the `applicationData`. How can I solve this problem? Idle in the second thread until the data is available?

**Edit**

In my C++ code I'm creating a new object of the java class that I want to call:

```
jmethodID javaClassConstructor= env->GetMethodID(javaClass, "<init>", "()V");
                    jobject serviceObject = env->NewObject(javaClass, serviceConstructor);
jobject javaClassObject = env->NewObject(javaClass, javaClassConstructor);
```

After that I call the code as shown above. After more debugging I can say that the method is called in a thread named `Thread-2` (I don't know if that is the c++ thread or a new one from JNI). It is definitely not the java main thread. However the work of the method is interrupted. That means If I debug the code, I can see that the data would be set soon but in the next debug step the `getApplicationData` method is executed (which can only occur if c++ is calling it).

**Edit**
The Java method I call:

```
public int receive(int methodId, byte[] data, ServiceResult result){
        log.info("java enter methodID = " + methodId + ", data= " + data);  

        long responseCode = SEC_ERR_CODE_SUCCESS;

        JavaMessageProto msg;
        try {
            msg = JavaMessageProto (data);
            log.info("principal: " + msg.getPrincipal());       
            JavaMessage message = new JavaMessage (msg);

            if(methodId == GET_LISTS){
                //this is shown in console
                System.out.println("get lists");                
                responseCode = getLists(message);
                //this point is not reached 
                log.info("leave");  
            }           
            //[... different method calls here...]
            if(responseCode != SEC_ERR_CODE_METHOD_NOT_IMPLEMENTED){
                //ToDoListMessageProto response = message.getProtoBuf();
                JavaMessageProto response = JavaMessageProto.newBuilder()   
                        .setToken(message.getToken())
                        .setPrincipal(message.getPrincipal()).build();
                byte[] res = response.toByteArray();                
                result.setApplicationData(response.toByteArray());
            }
            else{
                result.setApplicationData("");
            }

        } catch (InvalidProtocolBufferException e) {
            responseCode = SEC_ERR_CODE_DATA_CORRUPTED;
            log.severe("Error: Could not parse Client message." + e.getMessage());
        }               

        result.setResponseCode((int)responseCode);
        return 0;
    }
```

The second method is

```
public long getLists(JavaMessage message) {
log.info("getLists enter");

String principal = message.getPrincipal();
String token = message.getToken();  

if(principal == null || principal.isEmpty()){           
    return SEC_ERR_CODE_PRINCIPAL_EMPTY;
}       
if(token == null || token.isEmpty()){       
    return SEC_ERR_CODE_NO_AUTHENTICATION;
}       

//get user object for authorization
SubjectManager manager = new SubjectManager();
Subject user = manager.getSubject();

user.setPrincipal(principal);
long result = user.isAuthenticated(token);
if(result != SEC_ERR_CODE_SUCCESS){
    return result;
}   
try {
    //fetch all user list names and ids         
    ToDoListDAO db = new ToDoListDAO();     
    Connection conn = db.getConnection();       
    log.info( principal + " is authenticated");
    result = db.getLists(conn, message);
    //this is printed
    log.info( principal + " is authenticated");         
    conn.close();   //no exception here
    message.addId("testentry");
    //this not          
    log.info("Fetched lists finished for " + principal);
} catch (SQLException e) {  
    log.severe("SQLException:" + e.getMessage());
    result = SEC_ERR_CODE_DATABASE_ERROR;
}           

return result;
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify the description of your problem? You first say that "javaReceiveMethod" is executed on the C++ thread and then you say it's executed on the main thread? Btw, the method calls are executed synchronously.

Comment: I will update my answer and try to describe it as clear as possble. But at the moment I'm very confused what exactly JNI is doing there.

Comment: You haven't shown us the Java method that you're calling.

Comment: JNI itself doesn't create a new thread, so Thread-2 should be your C++ thread. You can set the thread name in the JavaVMAttachArgs arg to AttachCurrentThread() btw.

Comment: Do you really call result.setApplicationData() in the methodId == GET_LISTS case?

Comment: Yes I do. The problem was caused by a NullPointerException, as descripted in my response to marcinj answer. Anyway I will add flag to the object class which handles the result to indicate if any application data is contained in the result. If the flag is false I will just skip the call to getApplicationData to prevent any further problems.

Comment: As a general advice for JNI coding: it really pays off in the long run to have a wrapper for all JNI functions that does all the checks for you (return codes, ExceptionOccurred() and so on) and throws a C++ exception if something went wrong. We are using such a wrapper since 2003 and it saved our butts more than once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CallVoidMethod` is executed synchronously.

Maybe you have an excepion on c++ side?, do you use c++ jni exception checks?:

```
env->CallVoidMethod(javaClassObject, javaReceiveMethod, intParam, byteParam, objectParam);
if(env->ExceptionOccurred()) {
   // Print exception caused by CallVoidMethod
   env->ExceptionDescribe();
   env->ExceptionClear();
}
```

> The C++ code (in a shared object library) is running in it's own C++ thread. It is using a existing JavaVM of a java app that is already up and running.

its not clear whether you have attached current thread to virtual machine. Make  sure `env` is comming from `AttachCurrentThread` call. You will find example here: [How to obtain JNI interface pointer (JNIEnv *) for asynchronous calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12900695/how-to-obtain-jni-interface-pointer-jnienv-for-asynchronous-calls).

Comment: the thread is attached. I call vm->AttachCurrentThread((void**)&env, NULL);

Comment: It was indeed a exception that was thrown in my Java code but not shown on Java side. The `addId` Method caused a `NullPointerException` and in my naive believe that Java would show such a exception in my development environment I couldn't believe this strange behaviour would be caused by such a stupid bug. Sorry for any  inconvenience. Thank you very much for pointing me to `env->ExceptionOccured`. I'm still new to JNI and didn't know that I can catch exceptions in this way.