# Is calling AttachCurrentThread on JNI costly?

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface

I've found here https://stackoverflow.com/a/12901159/6655884 a function call where it attaches the thread with `AttachCurrentThread`, does the call and then detaches it with `DetachCurrentThread`.

I want to know if this process is costly. I have a C++ function

```
void sendEvent(Event event) {
    //call java function here
}
```

that will be called by several C++ threads to send events to the Java side, so I cannot simply attach a thread and never detach it because many different threads are going to call `sendEvent`. So I wanna know if doing `AttachCurrentThread`, calling Java and then `DetachCurrentThread` at every `sendEvent` call is costly. If it is, what should I do instead?

Comment: You can set up a thread destructor callback to detach the thread from the JVM when the thread is destroyed. See the final part of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30026030/what-is-the-best-way-to-save-jnienv/30026231#30026231  Note that with recent NDK versions you can accomplish the same thing with even less code using `thread_local`s.

Comment: Attaching and detaching threads are costly operations, which could cost you tens of milliseconds in bad conditions. In your situation, it'd be better to use some kind of pool of pre-attached threads or one attached thread with task queue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although you CAN attach the calling thread on a per-JNI-call basic, you really SHOULD NOT, unless you have no other choice.  A native thread MUST attach itself to the JVM before it can make JNI calls.  To avoid unnecessary overhead, the thread really should attach itself as soon as possible (at least before the 1st JNI call), and stay attached until it no longer needs to make any further JNI calls.